# Query records having ALL ManyToMany ids

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to query for a certain record that has ALL defined related records.

The example speaks for itself:

```
$qb->select('p')
   ->from('CommonBundle:MyTerm', 'p')
   ->leftJoin('p.propertyTypes','pt')
   ->where('pt.id IN (:ids)')
   ->setParameter('ids', array(1, 2, 3));
```

This will return all the records that have associated pt.id 1, 2 or 3.

But I want records that have associated ids 1, 2 AND 3,
any idea how I can do that? Or should I use "group by"s and counts?

Comment: Make a regular sql query that works and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by joining the same table twice, like this:

```
$qb->select('COUNT(DISTINCT ptnot.id) AS ptnotcount, p')
   ->from('CommonBundle:MyTerm', 'p')
   ->leftJoin('p.propertyTypes','pt')
   ->leftJoin('p.propertyTypes','ptnot')
   ->where('(pt.id in (:ids) OR ptnot.id in (:notids))')
   ->setParameter('ids', array(1, 2, 3))
   ->setParameter('notids', array(4, 5, 6))
   ->groupBy('p.id')
   ->having('ptnotcount = 3'); // Size of the 'ids' array
```

I'm basically querying everything that *should* be there, and everything that *shouldn't* be there, too.

Then I see if the count of all the distinct `propertyTypes` id's match wat we want.